# Could not set unknown property 'mainClass' for object of type org.springframework.boot.gradle.dsl.SpringBootExtension

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have the main `build.gradle` file for the project

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${spring_boot_version}")
    }
}

def javaProjects = subprojects.findAll {
    it.name in ["common", "core", "web", "app"]
}

allprojects {
    apply plugin: 'idea'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

idea {
    project {
        jdkName = "1.8"
        languageLevel = "1.8"
        vcs = "Git"
    }
}

configure(javaProjects) {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
    apply plugin: 'findbugs'

    sourceCompatibility = 1.8
    targetCompatibility = 1.8

    dependencies {
        ...
    }
}
```

and the `build.gradle` file for the `app` module, where I have a configuration to run gradle

```
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'

dependencies {
    ...
}

springBoot {
    mainClass = "com.web.WebApplication"
}

jar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Implementation-Title': "Rest-Web-Services",
                'Implementation-Version': "1.0",
                'Main-Class': "com.web.WebApplication"
    }
}
```

when build gradle throws

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '...\REST-Web-Services\app\build.gradle' line: 28

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not set unknown property 'mainClass' for object of type org.springframework.boot.gradle.dsl.SpringBootExtension.
```

How to set the startup `mainClass` class?

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the Spring example code [here.](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/#scratch)

Answer (score 8):

***Configuring the main class***

By default, the executable archive’s main class will be configured automatically by looking for a class with a `public static void main(String[])` method in directories on the task’s classpath.

The main class can also be configured explicitly using the task’s `mainClassName` property:

```
bootJar {
    mainClassName = 'com.example.ExampleApplication'
}
```

Alternatively, the main class name can be configured project-wide using the `mainClassName` property of the Spring Boot DSL:

```
springBoot {
    mainClassName = 'com.example.ExampleApplication'
}
```

If the application plugin has been applied its `mainClassName` project property can be used for the same purpose:

```
mainClassName = 'com.example.ExampleApplication'
```

Lastly, the `Start-Class` attribute can be configured on the task’s manifest:

```
bootJar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Start-Class': 'com.example.ExampleApplication'
    }
}
```

[Refrance](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/gradle-plugin/reference/html/)

Answer (score 7):

Basically, this is about `spring-boot gradle plugin`:

- bevore verion springboot2, it useed `mainClass` property,
- since [v2.0.0.RELEASE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-configuring-main-class), it changed to use `mainClassName`.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the Spring Restful Service [tutorial](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/#scratch) that does not have the declaration,and it worked.  Try removing the `mainClass` declaration.

> The Spring Boot gradle plugin provides many convenient features:
>
> It collects all the jars on the classpath and builds a single, runnable "über-jar", which makes it more convenient to execute and transport your service.
>
> It searches for the public static void main() method to flag as a runnable class.
>
> It provides a built-in dependency resolver that sets the version number to match Spring Boot dependencies. You can override any version you wish, but it will default to Boot’s chosen set of versions.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR**

Define following block in you Gradle build script:

```
springBoot {
  mainClass = 'com.example.ExampleApplication'
}
```

**Error**

With the **org.springframework.boot** Gradle plugin version 2.6.2.

```
plugins {
  id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.0'
}
```

I had similar issue.

> Execution failed for task ':bootJar'.
> Failed to calculate the value of task ':bootJar' property 'mainClass'.
> Main class name has not been configured and it could not be resolved

Spring has again changed convention of how to provide main class since @leo has provided an answer for this reason I will extend it. Now depending on the version of the springframework.boot plugin you have to define the main class value on following way (sorted from newest to oldest):

---

**[SpringFramework 2.4.0 and newer](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.0/gradle-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#packaging-executable-configuring-main-class)**

```
springBoot {
  mainClass = 'com.example.ExampleApplication'
}
```

[Release/Migration notes for 2.4.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes#spring-boot-gradle-plugin)

---

**[SpringFramework 2.3.12 and older](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.3.12.RELEASE/gradle-plugin/reference/html/#packaging-executable-configuring-main-class)**

```
springBoot {
  mainClassName = 'com.example.ExampleApplication'
}
```

[Release/Migration notes for 2.0.0](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.0-Migration-Guide#configuration-updates)

---

**[SpringFramework 1.5.22.RELEASE and older](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.22.RELEASE/reference/html/build-tool-plugins-gradle-plugin.html#build-tool-plugins-gradle-repackage-configuration)** (Hopefully you are not using that anymore)

```
bootRepackage {
  mainClass = 'demo.Application'
}
```